# How to use clickable button on Android app in python using Kivy?

Tags: android, python, api, button, kivy

I'm new here but used to read a lot from this forum so I hope you could help me.

I want to create an app on Android as simple as possible (just for a test and future design) using python, so I choose Kivy to do it for now. This app would just have a button and give the weather of a specific location by pressing a button named on this location.
I succeeded to run it on windows with my cmd but when I open my app using Kivy Launcher on my phone the app crashes before I could do anything. Can someone tell me why ? :o (other examples apps works on my phone with Kivy Launcher)

Here is my code :

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import requests

class Main (GridLayout):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        super (Main, self). __init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.paris = Button(text='Paris', font_size=40, on_press=lambda a:get_meteo(ville = "Paris"))
        self.add_widget(self.paris)
        self.rio = Button(text='Rio de Janeiro', font_size=40, on_press=lambda a:get_meteo(ville = "Rio de Janeiro, BR"))
        self.add_widget(self.rio)

def get_meteo(ville):   # Obtention de la météo d'une ville.
        print("confirmed")
        meteo = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + ville + ",fr&appid=myID").json()
        print (meteo)

class MeteoApp(App):
    icon = 'icon.png'
    def build(self):
        return Main()

MeteoApp().run()
```

Comment: I think that kivy launcher uses kivy 1.9.1, so you must change your `kivy.require` line...

Comment: I tried but that didnt work better... thanks for the try :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use python-for-android tool to build APK and use your application without Kivy launcher. Also, you may try to use Android Debugger Bridge for Linux - adb (eg. for Ubuntu you can install it by `sudo apt install adb`) to sort out what is the reason of your problem.

The way how you can check it with built APK:

1. Connect your device in Developers mode to PC where you made your APK
   and where adb is installed. You should do it via usb-cable.
2. Connect adb to device. More details are here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb
3. Remove from your device previous broken version of your APK.
4. Run command in Terminal: `adb install -r yourAppName.apk`. You may use your broken version. It should take some time, but you
   should get `success` message in Terminal as a result. This step
   mostly is needed to be sure that adb is connected to device
   properly.
5. Run your APK on device. It will crash.
6. Run command in Terminal on PC: `adb logcat | grep python` or `adb logcat | grep kivy`. Or just `adb logcat` to get full output.
7. You will get logs from your device and see it in Terminal.

Perhaps, your problem is closely connected with this: [Kivy application does not work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130751/kivy-application-does-not-work-on-android/55280549#55280549)
and can be solved by installing the freshest version of python-for-android from their github Master branch.